# iOS App sqlite performance slow down

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I create an application with a big database (100 Mo).
When my app is open and no others apps are in background, my sqlite request is ok (it take  1 second). If I open Facebook for example and I open my app, the same request take 5 seconds (in iPhone 5s et 6).

I think the memory for my app is less important when Facebook is in background.

have you an idea ?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem since your app is in foreground, the iOS is prioritizing its process and reduced memory consumption by other apps, until even killing the background apps processes. You should better profile your requests and check the timing functions, to find out which of your code takes long time to execute.

Comment: The question is not how large the database file is, but how much data you are actually accessing. Show the database schema and the slow queries.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The table have 50 000 elements. I create index correctly. For information, i have no the problem with same database in Android.